# Access cart data object to create total amount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, material-ui

im creating an array for list cart items, works well, but wanted to know how can i access to each item properties to create the total order amount outside table item

```
                    <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell className={classes.hideOnMobile}>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>PRODUCTO</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>PRECIO</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="center">CANTIDAD</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">TOTAL</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right"></TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {data.map((row) => (
                                <Item data={row} {...props} />
                            ))}
                        </TableBody>
                    <TableFooter className={classes.table}>
                        <TableCell>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">TOTAL ORDER</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="left">"TOTAL GOES HERE"</TableCell>
                    </TableFooter>
                    </Table>
```

This is my JSON data

```
0:
  id: 31
  image: "https://example.com/test.jpg"
  name: "Product name 1"
  price: 3
  quantity: 13
  total: 39
__proto__: Object
1: {id: 2, name: "Product name 2", price: 3, …}
length: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a `total` variable somewhere in the component (a class property in this example, could very well just be a variable if you are using functional components), and accumulate the total as you loop over your data.  That way, you only have to loop over your data set once.  Something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component { 

 data = {/* your data */}
 total = 0;

render() {
 return (
  <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell className={classes.hideOnMobile}>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>PRODUCTO</TableCell>
        <TableCell>PRECIO</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center">CANTIDAD</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">TOTAL</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right"></TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
      {this.data.map((row) => (
       this.total += row.total;
       return <Item data={row} {...props} />
       ))}
     </TableBody>
     <TableFooter className={classes.table}>
       <TableCell>
       </TableCell>
       <TableCell align="right">TOTAL ORDER</TableCell>
       <TableCell align="left">{this.total}</TableCell>
     </TableFooter>
   </Table>
  );
}
```